# How to set ValidatorEnable() javascript attribute for a validator?

Tags: asp.net

I have a validator which I can enable or disable using the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ValidatorEnable($("#<%=validator2.ClientID%>")[0], true);
</script>
```

How can I set this attribute of the validator using C# in the code behind?

I have tried using the following C# but it didn't work:

```
validator2.Enabled = true;
```

What code do I need to use in the code behind to set `ValidatorEnable = true` for the Validator2 control? I have researched this on the net but couldn't find how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `Validation Group` of the validator in code behind

Answer (score 4):

The property is named [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enabled.aspx), not `Enable`:

```
validator2.Enabled = true;
```